# JBPM console 404- not found error

Tags: console, jbpm, wildfly-8

I am using Jbpm 6.1.0.Final and Wildfly 8.1.0.Final. After doing everything successfully, Jbpm console gives this error-> "**404-not found**". Please guide me here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37283348/1272428

Answer (score 3):

I dont know the exact answer but , I tried finding **server.log** in my installation folder , clean this file and save.

**wildfly-8.1.0.Final/standalone/log/server.log** (For my case)

Now its running

Cheers :)

Comment: Actually its inside the                                            wildfly-8.1.0.Final/standalone/log

Comment: How the heck possibly u guess this could be the problem though... will be helpful your assumption in future... running though;and this should be clean while ant clean.demo.. right?

Answer (score 2):

A probable cause for getting 404 is that you tried to open the console page before the server is up and running, Usually when you start the server, it will take less than 5 minutes to be up and running. Solution in this case: Try to open the console page only after the server is up.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I am sorry for the miscommunication. To the Author, or anyone who got this error, a probable cause for getting 404 is that you tried to open the console page before the server is up and running, Usually when you start the server, it will take less than 5 minutes to be up and running. Solution in this case: Try to open the console page only after the server is up.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a minute or two, it takes a while to load