# JBPM-console 404 not found

Tags: console, http-status-code-404, jbpm

I have successfully installed **JBPM 6.1.0.Final-Installer-Full**. While opening the console at `http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console` it shows `JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /jbpm-console`In the server administration console, it can be clearly seen that jbpm-cosole.war is successfully deployed.

Here is the log

```
12:40:35,812 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
12:40:35,812 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) JBAS010153: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
12:40:35,827 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) JBAS016300: Activating JacORB Subsystem
12:40:35,843 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
12:40:35,859 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) JBAS012605: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main, 1.2]
12:40:35,874 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
12:40:36,061 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
12:40:37,169 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Remoting version (unknown)
12:40:37,826 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.19.SP8-redhat-1
12:40:37,842 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
12:40:38,185 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.0.26.Final-redhat-1)
12:40:39,605 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
12:40:39,620 INFO  [org.jboss.jaxr] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS014000: Started JAXR subsystem, binding JAXR connection factory into JNDI as: java:jboss/jaxr/ConnectionFactory
12:40:39,636 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
12:40:40,512 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
12:40:40,543 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
12:40:40,668 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory D:\jbpm-6.1.0.Final-installer-full\jbpm-installer\jboss-eap-6.3.0\standalone\deployments
12:40:40,699 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "jbpm-console.war" (runtime-name: "jbpm-console.war")
12:40:40,933 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221000: live server is starting with configuration HornetQ Configuration (clustered=false,backup=false,sharedStore=true,journalDirectory=D:\jbpm-6.1.0.Final-installer-full\jbpm-installer\jboss-eap-6.3.0\standalone\data\messagingjournal,bindingsDirectory=D:\jbpm-6.1.0.Final-installer-full\jbpm-installer\jboss-eap-6.3.0\standalone\data\messagingbindings,largeMessagesDirectory=D:\jbpm-6.1.0.Final-installer-full\jbpm-installer\jboss-eap-6.3.0\standalone\data\messaginglargemessages,pagingDirectory=D:\jbpm-6.1.0.Final-installer-full\jbpm-installer\jboss-eap-6.3.0\standalone\data\messagingpaging)
12:40:40,933 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221006: Waiting to obtain live lock
12:40:41,260 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221013: Using NIO Journal
12:40:42,056 WARN  [jacorb.codeset] (MSC service thread 1-3) Warning - unknown codeset (Cp1252) - defaulting to ISO-8859-1
12:40:42,619 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221034: Waiting to obtain live lock
12:40:42,619 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock
12:40:42,790 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016330: CORBA ORB Service started
12:40:42,821 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
12:40:42,837 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
12:40:43,991 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016328: CORBA Naming Service started
12:40:45,302 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
12:40:45,302 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/jbpmDS]
12:40:46,628 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221020: Started Netty Acceptor version 3.6.9.Final-redhat-1-4cc400c 127.0.0.1:5445 for CORE protocol
12:40:46,628 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221020: Started Netty Acceptor version 3.6.9.Final-redhat-1-4cc400c 127.0.0.1:5455 for CORE protocol
12:40:46,643 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221007: Server is now live
12:40:46,643 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221001: HornetQ Server version 2.3.20.Final (2.3.20, 123) [517089d3-7ea9-11e4-88c9-2d52a55890f3] 
12:40:46,894 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
12:40:46,960 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
12:40:46,976 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3.0.Final-redhat-3
12:40:47,132 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010406: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
12:40:47,584 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue
12:40:47,584 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
12:40:47,600 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.DLQ
12:40:47,647 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/jms/queue/DLQ
12:40:47,662 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra] (MSC service thread 1-3) HornetQ resource adaptor started
12:40:47,662 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-3) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatorhornetq-ra
12:40:47,662 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010401: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
12:42:27,884 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "jbpm-console.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60-ea]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018774: Error loading jboss-all.xml from D:\jbpm-6.1.0.Final-installer-full\jbpm-installer\jboss-eap-6.3.0\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\temp6c761dcbf5747a8a\jbpm-console.war-2f4b0c1a30bca435\META-INF\jboss-all.xml
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.parse(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:153) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.parse(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:128) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.deploy(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:96) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[18,3]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:weld:1.0}weld'
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor$Parser.parseJBossElement(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:203) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor$Parser.readElement(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:192) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor$Parser.readElement(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:176) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.parse(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:148) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    ... 8 more

12:42:28,067 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS018559: Deployed "jbpm-console.war" (runtime-name : "jbpm-console.war")
12:42:28,072 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "jbpm-console.war"

12:42:28,541 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
12:42:28,545 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
12:42:28,549 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) started (with errors) in 125341ms - Started 197 of 235 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 67 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Please guide me here.

Answer (score 4):

I was having same issue while I was following steps here to install jBPM:
http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.3/userguide/ch03.html

I got stuck on

```
tart.h2.check:
      [echo] Checking if h2 db should be started ... 
start.h2: 

start.jboss: 

start.demo.noeclipse:   

BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 14 seconds
```

I was getting Error 404 in
http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console

What I needed to do was visit WildFly administrative console
http://localhost:8080/console

and found out that a user must be created using

> \jbpm-installer\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\bin\add-user.bat

That fixed my problem.

**But before any of that:**
Wait a minute or two, normally it takes a while to start.

Answer (score 0):

It failed to start the jbpm-console, having issues parsing the jboss-all.xml in the war.  Which application server are you using?  If you are trying to install on another server than the (default) Wildfly, try deleting the jbpm-console war from the lib directory so it can download the right war for the application server again.